# How to check if variable exist then print as string in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Using GAE's datastore I wish to print out a statement concatenated with variables turned into string.
This is my codesnippet were I loop through all entities of the `Article` kind:

```
    que = Article.query()

    testt = que.fetch(1000)
    for t in testt:
        self.response.write(t.title)
        self.response.write("<b>Artikel:</b> "+t.title + " <b>Forfatter:</b> "+t.author + " <b>Udgivet:</b> " 
        + t.time + " <b>Likes:</b> " + str(t.likes) + " <b>Shares:</b> " + str(t.shares) + " <b>Comments:</b> " + str(t.comments))
```

However some of these variables may not exist. And I'm guessing this error is because I'm trying to convert Null-values?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tipcrawl/1.383603861670919963/main.py", line 134, in get
+ t.time + " <b>Likes:</b> " + str(t.likes) + " <b>Shares:</b> " + str(t.shares) + " <b>Comments:</b> " + str(t.comments))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

So my question is how can I call an `if t.likes` statement to check if the variable has a value and concatenate on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would store the output in a string var and I will be appending what needed when the var exists:

```
testt = que.fetch(1000)
for t in testt:
    self.response.write(t.title)
    textToWrite = str()
    if t.title:
        textToWrite += "<b>Artikel:</b> "+ t.title
    if t.author:
        textToWrite += " <b>Forfatter:</b> "+t.author

    # ....
    # and other vars

    #finally, write it
    self.response.write(textToWrite)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It is probably the best and least error prone way to do it I guess